# Grammaticality judgments misaligned using gb4e package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, gb4e

I am writing my dissertation in Linguistics and use `gb4e` for the examples. When I try to add grammaticality judgments they appear indented, meaning aligned with the beginning of another example that is has no grammaticality judgment:

a. *The man is here who is carrying a large package.
b. A man is here who is carrying a large package.

The example sentences should all be aligned and any grammaticality judgments should appear on the left. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}

The example in \eqref{gs1} is ungrammatical. The example in \eqref{gs2} is fine.

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex[*]{The man is here who is carrying a large package.} \label{gs1}
\ex A man is here who is carrying a large package. \label{gs2}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certainly no expert, but after glancing at the documentation it appears you need

```
\ex[]{A man is here who is carrying a large package.}
```

for the second one.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}

The example in \eqref{gs1} is ungrammatical. The example in \eqref{gs2} is fine.

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex[*]{The man is here who is carrying a large package.} \label{gs1}
\ex[]{A man is here who is carrying a large package.} \label{gs2}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I am wondering if the spacing between the 'a.' and the '*' is a bit much, but maybe my eyes deceive me. Maybe it's normal that when you have grammaticality judgments, the spacing is wider than when you have only examples without judgments.

Comment: @reenah You could add `\judgewidth{*}` (see manual page 4) after `\begin{exe}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I would only recommend  setting `\judgewidth` globally, so that all your examples are consistent. But that's the source of the extra space, since the default is set to allow enough space for `??` as a judgement.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, good point.

Comment: @reenah See Alan's comment, adding it before `\begin{document}` would be better.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. @AlanMunn  Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. I won't apply it this time, because I have some examples which have `??` judgments.